# Crash-free statistics monitor not working in Firebase Crashlytics in Flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, crashlytics, google-fabric, crashlytics-android

I tried to set-up Firebase Crashlytics in my Flutter application. Everything works and crashes are collected properly now except for one thing. Crash-free monitor is not working and I really can do nothing with that. I see this kind of message instead of data all the time:

[image]

1) `pubspec.yaml` contains following dependencies:

```
firebase_crashlytics: 0.1.2+4
firebase_core: 0.4.3+2
firebase_messaging: 6.0.9
firebase_analytics: 5.0.9
```

2) `runner.dart`

```dart
void run() async {
  // закрепляем ориентацию todo изменить на необходимое или убрать
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp]);

  _initCrashlytics();
  _initLogger();
  _runApp();
}

void _runApp() {
  runZoned<Future<void>>(
    () async {
      runApp(App());
    },
    onError: Crashlytics.instance.recordError,
  );
}

void _initCrashlytics() {
  FlutterError.onError = Crashlytics.instance.recordFlutterError;
}

void _initLogger() {
  RemoteLogger.addStrategy(CrashlyticsRemoteLogStrategy());
  Logger.addStrategy(DebugLogStrategy());
  Logger.addStrategy(RemoteLogStrategy());
}
```

3) `build.gradle (android)`

```
classpath 'io.fabric.tools:gradle:1.31.2'
```

4) `build.gradle (android/app)`

```
apply plugin: 'io.fabric'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

No errors in LogCat, no warnings, nothing. I see successful initialization message in logs every time application starts:

```
2020-01-10 12:27:32.691 23082-23082/ru.app.biz.client.android.debug I/FirebaseInitProvider: FirebaseApp initialization successful
```

I even tried to add Google Analytics dependency directly into my Android module but with no luck. Both Android and iOS applications are under this issue.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, I found the answer. Google Analytics was disabled in my Firebase project settings and it caused issues with crash-free widget.

Here are steps to fix it:

1) Go to project settings in your Firebase project console;
2) Move to the "Integrations" tab;
3) Click "Enable" on Google Analytics widget and go through all necessary steps;
4) Wait a while to see the result.

[image: Guide]

Comment: Same problem happens to me. can you describe some of the "necessary steps" in (3)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know exactly, but I see some problems in your settings:

1. There is no need to add firebase_core, firebase_analytics enough as google said:
   [image]
2. You forgot to add `classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'` to your `build.gradle (android)`
3. Maybe your project new and it doesn't have enough information to show.

Comment: When did you get this message image from? The Firebase documentation for setting up Flutter still says firebase-core is required: https://firebase.google.com/docs/flutter/setup?platform=android